# htaccess url rewrite with question mark

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a problem in `.htaccess`, specifically on redirection.

I wanted to rewrite this url:

```
http://www.domain.com/?mod=country
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/country
```

I already tried this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\?mod=(.*)$ $1
```

I tried working on it without the question mark character and it works fine.
I have escaped the question mark because it's part of the special characters, but still, I couldn't get it work.

Can you tell what I'm missing?

Comment: you want `/country` to go to `/?mod=country`?

Comment: `RewriteRule`'s are not for redirecting users.

Comment: Don't you mean the other way around? When a visitor types `www.foo.com/country` it should internally be seen as `?mod=country`?

Comment: @BookOfZeus /?mod=country to /country

Comment: @jaysonatic you want a permanent redirect from /?mod=country to /country?

Comment: @Qtax I'm doing this because I wanted to get rid of dynamic urls.

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yes sir, I wanted a permanent redirect.

Comment: @jaysonatic Check qtax answer and instead of [QSA] use [R=301,L]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly translating your requirements to rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mod=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ %1
```

But you probably want something more flexible like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)mod=([^&]+)
RewriteRule /?(.*) %1/$1 [QSA]
```

These rules apply to the root of your domain.

If you want to do an external redirect add the `R` flag to the rewrite rule.

Comment: The first code outputs: http://www.domain.com/country_data?mod=country_data, I wanted it to be just /country_data. Thanks.

Comment: how do I remove the trailing ?mod=country_data?

Comment: @jaysonatic To remove the querystring add a `?` i.e change the rule to `RewriteRule ^$ %1?`

Comment: @UlrichPalha output is just the same, i'm using `htaccess.madewithlove.be` to check htaccess code.

Comment: @jaysonatic The site does say `This was made in a very short amount of time, so there might be a few bugs we overlooked` - so I would test it locally

Comment: @jay, `RewriteRule ^$ %1? [R=301]`