# HTACCESS Redirect from URL including ? to static page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a couple of hits everyday from a now defunct tutorial I wrote. Rather than letting them sit on the 404, I have created a page with links to more up to date ones in the hope that someone else can help.

I am attempting to edit my htaccess to rediret

My site is WP powered and the incoming link is

```
/tutorials/?p=3
```

I would like it to go to:

```
/wiki/sorry-this-tutorial-no-longer-exists
```

I have tried:

```
Redirect /tutorials/?p=3 http://domain.com/wiki/sorry-this-tutorial-no-longer-exists
```

The closest I got was

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tutorials/?(.*)  http://domain.com/wiki/sorry-this-tutorial-no-longer-exists
```

But that of course sticks the ...exists/?p=3 on the end which doesn't work

Any help with the bloody question mark? (I tried [htaccess url rewrite with question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254742/htaccess-url-rewrite-with-question-mark) but it would not work?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you are looking for

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/tutorials/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/wiki/sorry-this-tutorial-no-longer-exists? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Yes, this looks more like it. However, this still gives me a http://domain.com/wiki/sorry-this-tutorial-no-longer-exists/?p=3 result. Anyway to remove the ?p=3

Comment: Apologies I missed the ? off the end. I have updated the answer

Comment: just a detail but use `^\bp=3\b` otherwise query patterns like `?cab=300` will get matched.

Comment: Good stuff! Works perfectly now. Many thanks for the fix and @TerryE for the tweak.